# How can post images using slack-api in gallery view instead of slack formatting them vertically?

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

so my question is actually self-explanatory, if you use the slack client and post a message with 1 or more images, slack displays them in a gallery view, but when you try do achieve this using the api, this doesn't seem to be working, slack starts displaying them vertically which sometimes takes the entire viewport of a user and gets annoying.

Here's an example of what I mean:
this is how slack displays the images when posted using the client itself.
[image]

and this is how slack displays it when posted through api
[image]

So how can I achieve the former but using the API?

Comment: Can you provide details of the API your are using? Are you attaching the image or are you using image URL from publicly accessible link? If you are using link, you can make use of block kit to format your message.

Comment: @SuyashGaur I am using an external image link and attaching it inside a slack block, it still doesn't work the way i want

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the feature that you request is only available with slack client.

 **Slack *does not allow* this feature by block kit nor by using any API.**